# Cannot sign in a user to Facebook using Parse

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an app which uses Parse as a backend and requires users to log in through Facebook. I have created an app on facebook and am following all the instructions to implement it, but I get a weird error. Users are taken to the permissions page, and once they log in and accept they are taken back to my app. The app doesn't crash but I receive this error message and the user ends up nil:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x6a24d80
{error=<CFBasicHash 0x6a23dc0     [0x1925b38]>
{type = mutable dict, count = 4,
entries =>
2 : <CFString 0x6a24110 [0x1925b38]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x6a242f0 [0x1925b38]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
3 : <CFString 0x6a24290 [0x1925b38]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x6a241a0 [0x1925b38]>{contents =
    "Error validating access token:
     Session is invalid. This could be because the application was uninstalled
     after the session was created."}
6 : <CFString 0x6a24b30 [0x1925b38]>{contents = "code"} = 190
11 : <CFString 0x6a24c70 [0x1925b38]>{contents = "error_subcode"} = 461
}
}
```

I am almost sure this is a problem on facebook's end as I even tried logging in with Parse's sample project, which yields the same results. But, just in case, here is my code for logging a user in.

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me",
                             @"user_relationships",@"user_birthday",@"user_location",
                             @"offline_access", nil];

[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
    NSLog(@"user %@", user);
}];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,